# Advantages of Telnet over SSH?

Tags: ssh, telnet

SSH is the recommended protocol for remote configurations. Still, telnet is being used in many devices. Are there any advantages of telnet over SSH?

Comment: Telnet is *simple*! That's all, really.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, let's see:

- Telnet is simpler (as others have noted already);
- Telnet is obviously faster, as the protocol is much more trivial and there is no key exchange and no encryption involved;
- Telnet is less vulnerable

Wait, stop, WHAT !?

Well, yes, telnet protocol is plain-text, so you can just sniff the connection and now you know the password and everything else.
And that is a well known fact indeed.

How hard would it be to actually sniff the particular telnet session,
depends on the network setup and a bunch of other things, and might range from being completely trivial to extremely hard to do.

But aside the (obvious) lack of encryption, when it comes to protocol and the service implementation(s) itself, which one is less vulnerable in overall ?

Let's take a look in the CVE database:

Telnet: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=telnet

There were 5 vulnerabilities, registered in 2016,
3 of them are just "hardcoded credentials", which is more of a vendor error than a real service implementation or protocol flaw.

Now, SSH: https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=ssh

25 (!) vulnerabilities (year 2016), ranging from the "hard-coded" credentials to allowing the selection of low-security encryption algorithms, issues which allow for denial-of-service attacks or reading the private keys from the remote process memory and so on.

So there were obviously many more SSH related vulnerabilities than Telnet vulnerabilities detected in 2016, and Telnet is a winner here.

That is actually pretty logical, taking that SSH is a much more complex protocol, and a typical SSH implementation will have many more features, like X11 forwarding, file transfer, tunnels e.t.c.,requiring a more complex code, and making a much wider "attack surface"

Please take the above with a grain of salt, Telnet is still plain-text
and it is widely regarded as an outdated protocol, so you definitely have to use a decent SSH implementation instead.

Just make sure that it is configured properly (e.g. switch off features you are not going to use), and keep it up to date at all times.

At the same time, you have to remember that sometimes "obvious things" are not always that "obvious", when you look at them at a bit different angle,
and that is the point of this post.

Comment: Evaluating a protocol by the number of CVE has to be one of the worst possible way to measure its security. This is the equivalent of saying, you're better off living in a tent because there is only a limited number of way to break into a tent, versus behind a locked door because there are millions of way to bypass a lock.

Comment: No one cares about attacking telnet because no one uses it

Answer (score 1):

Probably telnet is simpler but it might be historical reasons as well.